# I'm getting javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch! when decrypting large files using AES/GCM/NoPadding

Tags: java, encryption

I have been using BouncyCastle's provider to encrypt files using "AES/GCM/NoPadding" as the transformation.  It has worked for lots of smaller files.  But, with larger files I am getting the exception:

javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!

Here is the code I am using to encrypt:

```
    try (DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(encryptedFile))) {
        os.writeInt(CURRENT_ENCRYPTION_FILE_VERSION);
        os.writeInt(CURRENT_RSA_KEY_VERSION);

        // Generate a new random symmetric key for the AES encryption cipher
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGenerator.init(128);
        SecretKey aesKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();

        // Write the RSA encrypted AES key to the file
        os.write(doRsaTransformation(aesKey.getEncoded(), publicRsaKey, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE));

        // Generate an initialization vector (IV)
        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        sr.nextBytes(iv);

        // Write the RSA encrypted IV to the file
        os.write(doRsaTransformation(iv, publicRsaKey, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE));

        // Write the encrypted file
        doAesFileEncryption(fileToEncrypt, aesKey, iv, os);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchPaddingException | IOException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
        throw new EncryptionException(ex);
    }

private void doAesFileEncryption(File fileToEncrypt, SecretKey aesKey, byte[] iv, OutputStream os) {
        Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey, new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv));

        byte[] block = new byte[1024];
    int i;
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToEncrypt)) {
        while ((i = fis.read(block)) != -1) {
            byte[] encryptedBlock = aesCipher.update(block, 0, i);
            if (encryptedBlock != null) {
                os.write(encryptedBlock);
            }
        }
        byte[] encryptedFinal = aesCipher.doFinal();
        if (encryptedFinal != null) {
            os.write(encryptedFinal);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code I am using to decrypt:

```
    Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey, new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv));

    byte[] block = new byte[1073741824];
    int i;
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(decryptedFile)) {
        while ((i = is.read(block)) != -1) {
            byte[] decryptedBlock = aesCipher.update(block, 0, i);
            if (decryptedBlock != null) {
                fos.write(decryptedBlock);
            }
        }
        byte[] decryptedFinal = aesCipher.doFinal();
        if (decryptedFinal != null) {
            fos.write(decryptedFinal);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
I have been trying to figure this out for days now.  Luckily, I have at least figured out how to decrypt a file that I desperately needed!

The file was being encrypted on a server that was running Java 7 update 51.  (I know I'm bad for not keeping it up to date.)  Now I'm trying to decrypt it on my local computer (and other local computers) that are running Java 8.  I always get the above exception for the larger files, not the smaller ones.  If I decrypt the large file with Java 7, then it decrypts with no errors.

Is this behavior expected?  It seems to me that Java 8 should be able to decrypt large files that were encrypted with Java 7.

If I can't rely on the newer versions of Java decrypting files that were encrypted with older versions of Java, then how do I move forward?  Do I have to decrypt all of my files with the old version so that I can then encrypt them with the new version?

Thank you very much!  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is not full code. For instance, we cannot see if you correctly close the streams.

Comment: Thank you, @MaartenBodewes!  I was so focused on the encryption part that I did not even think about it being a stream issue.  This is the first application that I have used the try with resources block.  I was assuming that it would flush and close the streams for me.

Comment: It should but we didn't know that you used the try/catch :)

Comment: To be clear: you encrypted on *Oracle* Java 7u51 (since the non-Oracle javas don't usually use 'u'' in the version) with BC? Is decrypt also Oracle Java 8, and if so since Oracle Java 8 now has AES/GCM in SunJCE do you have code or config outside what you posted to get the BC provider? A problem occuring only on large data and thus a long(er) run suggests *possibly* a JIT problem; try running with `-Xint` and see if it's different (not just slower). Can you get the partial decrypt before doFinal throws, and see if it's a prefix of good plaintext or not?

Comment: Thank you, @dave_thompson_085!  Yes, I have installed several different updates of Oracle Java 7 to do the encryption as well as decryption.  I can decrypt the large files with any of the Oracle Java 7 updates.  I also tested decrypting using lots of different updates of Oracle Java 8.  I am not able to decrypt any of the large files with any of the Oracle Java 8 updates.  I do have code that loads the bouncy castle provider.  I will update this question with that code soon.  I'm glad you mentioned that!  I had not thought of that as a potential problem.

Comment: I know this is an old thread. Do you know the solution. Facing a similar issue.